# Would anyone know what the issue is with this sql query using pymysql in python?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Find_Student_ID =

```
"SELECT student_info.Student_ID FROM 

student_info JOIN user_information ON user_information.User_ID = student_info.User_ID 

WHERE user_information.User_Fname = '"+ str(User_Fname) + "' 

AND user_information.User_Fname = '"+ str(User_Lname)+"'"
```

The above sql query should use the 'User_Fname' and 'User_Lname' inputted by the user in the python code. These values are located in the user_information database, which should find the 'User_ID' from the same database and use the 'User_ID' as a foreign key to find the 'Student_ID' in the student_info table.

This query does not work, and instead returns a 'UnboundLocalError', saying the local variable 'Student_ID' cannot be accessed when it is not associated with a value.

I have tried messing around with the 'JOIN' and 'ON' sections as I suspect these are the problems and the system obviously isn't returning the expected 'Student_ID' value.

any help is great if you could, I have no clue what I have input wrong here.

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. (2) Format the code properly.

Comment: Maybe the issues are `'` and `"` characters

Answer (score 0):

just a query (get it?) for you,

user_information.User_Fname = '"+ str(User_Lname)+"'"

did you mean:

user_information.User_Lname = '"+ str(User_Lname)+"'"

cause it seems that you are trying to match the user's last name against any first names available.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much, I think this will fix it, I am so foolish for overlooking this.